# Filter out records with a wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using ElasticSearch + Kibana to log errors. In the Kibana dashboard, I can filter out records by a certain field by clicking on the magnifier glass with the minus sign. It then generates the following query to exclude:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": {
        "query": "Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '12.34.567.89'. You may need to add '12.34.567.89' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to exclude these records for all possible IP addresses, so I need a wildcard (or regexp). I found the documentation about wildcards and regexps [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_wildcard_and_regexp_queries.html). However, they do not resemble the syntax used above.

If I change the query above to the one from the documentation, it doesn't filter it at all. Example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "message": "Invalid HTTP_HOST header: *"
    }
  }
}
```

If I try to combine them, I get a parsing error: `Discover: [parsing_exception] [match] unknown token [START_OBJECT] after [query], with { line=1 col=444 }`. Example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": {
        "query": {
          "wildcard": {
            "message": "Invalid HTTP_HOST header: *"
          }
        },
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried a few more combinations, but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your `message` field have a `.keyword` sub-field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility is to use the [`regexp` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html), like this, but depending on how much data you have, it's going to be CPU intensive:

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "message.keyword": {"value":"Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '<1-999>\\.<1-999>\\.<1-999>\\.<1-999>'\\. You may need to add '<1-999>\\.<1-999>\\.<1-999>\\.<1-999>' to ALLOWED_HOSTS\\.",
      "flags": "ALL"}
    }
  }
}
```

You might be better off analyzing your data before indexing it and split it into better searchable parts.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried a regexp before, but couldn't get the syntax right. Probably I missed that keyword `flags`. I have changed it slightly to `{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "message.keyword": {
        "value": "Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '.*'. You may need to add '.*' to ALLOWED_HOSTS\\.",
        "flags": "ALL"
      }
    }
  }
}` now, since not all incoming hosts follow exactly the same pattern, but that works. :-)

Comment: I "only" have a few dozen errors per day in the log (so per index), so this regexp query shouldn't be too heavy. Thanks for the warning though!

Comment: Don't forget to escape the dot after the first IP address

Comment: Why is that necessary? A dot is not a reserved character in JSON, and that is why you have to escape the slashes, right?

Comment: A dot is a reserved character in the regexp language. See the one you have after `ALLOWED_HOSTS `

Comment: But in my query, I do mean the dot from the regexp language, so I should not escape it. The dot after `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is literally a dot indeed.

Comment: You have 4 dots, 2 for the IP addresses and 2 at the end of each sentences. Those latter two you need to escape with a double backslash

Comment: Ah, now I see! :-D I have it for the period at the end of the last sentence, but not for the period at the end of the first sentence! It happened to work, since a dot in regexp also filters a period character.

Comment: Anything else needed regarding your issue?

Comment: Nope, thanks a lot! I would have awarded the bounty yesterday already, but Stack Overflow enforces a 24 hour period before you can award it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds weird but it seems like it is not working because of upper case text.

Try this:

```
{
"query": {
    "wildcard": {
        "message": "*http_host*" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, the results are still not filtered out using this approach, nor when filtering out `?nvalid * header*`.

Answer (score 0):

Click on **Add filter** and then click on the top right corner of the dialog box **Edit as Query DSL**:

Case 1:
Case sensitive search containing the word **http_host** in the string.
Wildcard supports ? or * regex functionality only.

```
{
   "wildcard": {
      "message.keyword": "*http_host*"
   }
}
```

Case 2:
Case insensitive search containing the word **http_host** in the string.

```
{
  "query": {
     "multi_match": {
        "query": "http_host",
        "fields": [
           "message"  
        ],
        "type": "best_fields"
     }
 }
}
```